# Unable to access admin section of Wordpress using MAMP

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

I have been developing a Wordpress site locally using MAMP, and I have run into an issue twice now where when I leave at night and come back, I can't access the admin page. I have debugging on, and there aren't any fatal errors. I can access the front-end of the site just fine, but I can't log into the admin page. All I get is a white screen like:

[image]

Here is the front end:

[image]

As you can see the front end is working well, but I can't get into the admin section. I've tried to re-login and it just doesn't work.

What could be causing this? The last time this happened, I had to reinstall the entire site. I really don't want to do this every day. I know that everything was working when I left, and I haven't made any changes today.

Comment: Sounds like the session has timed out. Close the browser window/tab and try logging in again.

Comment: Did that and it doesn't work. Cleared the cache too... I've also tried in different browsers with the same result

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. 

Comment: @brasofilo "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow !!!!unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming!!!" - So please tell me how using MAMP to develop a custom plugin isn't related to programming? I'm also curious what else I would use a local installation of Wordpress for?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a problem with a brand new MAMP install along with a fresh WordPress install, with current files downloaded on 2020-06-08. MAMP installed perfectly. WordPress also installed perfectly, and the default website was accessible on my `localhost`. When I tried to login to `wp-admin`, however, I kept getting prompted to enter my username and password with no errors.

I followed every "fix" I could find and none of them worked. I uninstalled and reinstalled everything, created new databases, etc. multiple times with the same results.

After nearly 48 hours, I looked at MAMP preferences and went to the PHP tab and noticed there are two versions (7.3.9 and 7.4.2). I switched to 7.3.9 and I was able to login.

[image: MAMP PHP Preferences View]

Comment: Exact. Same. Problem. This fixed it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your plugins may be causing some trouble, as per this line:

> **Warning** opendir(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/tmm_shortcodes/views/.DS_Store/popups/): failed to open dir: Not a directory in **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/tmm_shortcodes/index.php** on line **148**

Try disabling the plugin through your PHPMyAdmin and try loading the admin page again. You should be able to find the list of active plugins in the `wp_options` table under 
`active_plugins`. Make sure to save a copy of the contents of that field in a text file, in case something goes wrong so you can reset it to the original parameter.

Comment: It was working yesterday with that same error. It's also a warning, rather than an error....

Comment: Are you using an outdated version of Wordpress? I ask because of the first line, with the mysql warning. There is supposed to be some kind of redirect I think, but it can't do that because of the warning message about the deprecated mysql function. You could try setting show_errors to no in php.ini to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is a very old post, but had this problem recently.

Found that my `wp-config-sample.php` file was missing a closing php tag `?>`. Amended that and the login worked fine.

Thought I'd add my experience here. Might help someone down the line!